# SQL Order by fails

Tags: php, mysql

How can I solve this little problem

here is a screenshot:

[image]

and this is the query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM serverinfo
ORDER BY rank_pts DESC
```

As you can see the order is incorect.

Answer (score 7):

You could try this:

```
ORDER BY CAST(rank_pts as float) DESC
```

Answer (score 4):

Seems your ranl_pts column is varchar type so it's not sorting as numbers.

Use below trick.

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM serverinfo
  ORDER BY rank_pts+0 DESC
```

OR

```
 SELECT * 
  FROM serverinfo
  ORDER BY CAST(rank_pts AS DOUBLE) desc
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably ought to change that column type to a float.  As the others have pointed out, it looks like its a varchar or text column.  If that's not the case and PHPMyAdmin is merely displaying it in a localized format ( decimals represented by, instead of . -- for us English folks ) please kindly disregard the rest of my answer.

While casting the result in your query would work as Alberto suggested, that's inefficent to do on every query.  If you want to manipulate and sort the data numerically, you should store it numerically.  Eventually you may want to display the numbers under a different localization, and you'll have another headache.

I would store the data as a float in the DB and handle any logic on how to display it in a localized format on the application side.

Comment: +1. Leave formatting to the front end. Storing formatted values makes applications very brittle.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend changing the column data type to be numeric and not character.  This will surely affect other parts of the code, but I think is worthwhile in order to avoid other side-effects of having a numeric value stored as it's character representation.

Obviously the quick fix is to cast the column in the `order by`, as fellow coders have already  pointed out.

Comment: I'm really disappointed that the many of up-voted questions here regard the quick fix, and not an actual solution.

Answer (score 0):

Change `rank_pts` to FLOAT  `*edit`.  It looks like its the wrong type to sort

Comment: Meh, +1 for realizing the type is probably varchar, but -1 for suggesting int when he clearly has decimal values he needs to store. So +0 from me.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM serverinfo
ORDER BY CAST(Rank_Pts AS DOUBLE) desc
```